# Problem calling MySQL stored procedure from php

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have a stored MySQL procedure that takes a customer number and a currency as input. It outputs an array using a select statement. The output array is comprised of Balance and NetBalance,

If I call the procedure from MySQL as "`call GetAccountBalanceByCurrency(500,'USD')`" I get the correct results.

However, if I call it from PHP as `$x= mysqli_multi_query("call GetAccountBalanceByCurrency(500,'USD');")`, I get the following error message:

```
Warning: mysqli_multi_query() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given 
    in C:\...\...\call_proc_test4.php on line 4.
```

I assume it is something simple, but have been banging my head for hours. I have tried `$x= mysqli_multi_query("call GetAccountBalanceByCurrency(500,'USD')");` among other things. Can anybody see the error?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the manual, the [`mysqli_multi_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) function requires two parameters, when you are using the procedural style API :

```
bool mysqli_multi_query  ( mysqli $link  , string $query  )
```

So, you at least must pass the link identifier as a first parameter.

BTW : that's exactly what the warning message is trying to indicate you ;-)

*"`mysqli_multi_query()` expects exactly **2** parameters, **1** given"*

Yes, the same manual page also gives an example with only one parameter -- but it's for the Object oriented style *(mysqli being an extension that exposes both a procedural and an OO API)*.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for mysqli_multi_query. The way you're calling it needs two arguments instead of just the one:

https://www.php.net/mysqli_multi_query

Answer (score 0):

**First you have to set 2 querys or one recource and one query
like this**

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$query  = "CREATE TABLE....;...;... blah blah blah;...";

mysqli_multi_query($link,$query);
```